# Hybris CPQ integration

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am setting up the SAP CPQ module for our Hybris platform and a question on the implementation had been raised. Due to some constraints, setting up the Data Hub might not be possible. What is the second best approach (if there is any) besides the Data Hub to ensure the data flow between sap and the cpq module ?

hedzs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other OOTB solution besides the Data Hub to ensure the data flow between SAP and CPQ.

If setting up the Data Hub is not possible, you will need to develop some custom solution.